# How to fetch a specific package updates?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, updates, update-manager, latex

I wan to update a [specific package](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee) (`biblatex-ieee`) that I use. I do not want to update my whole system (I need to maintain specific versions for some SWs). How to retrieve the updates of that specific package without updating the whole system?

Comment: Look up how use *apt-marking* or *apt-pinning* to prevent upgrades of specific packages. Then use the rest of your system normally.

Comment: @user535733 - Interesting...

Comment: Did you find any of what was posted useful?
It is good for the community to provide feedback.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to do

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-bibtex-extra
```

as this package [contains the needed *biblatex-ieee.** files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=biblatex-ieee).

Also from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/texlive-bibtex-extra :

> This package includes the following CTAN packages:
>   ...
>   `biblatex-ieee`
>   ...

Comment: I tried. This is what I get: E: Unable to locate package `biblatex-ieee`. It is not a full SW as far as I understand.

Comment: @seq - the answer now includes the correct package name for you.